# Realloc and SIGABRT

Tags: c, realloc

i'm making a program to discover the best path from one vertex to another. Well, i create the vertices, allocating memory for a list of neighbors. When i create a connection between two vertices, i realloc the memory of the list to add one more vertex to the neighbors list. It seems to work in the first two times, but then in the third time it crashes and gives me the signal "SIGABRT".I couldn't find the solution for the problem in any forum. This is my code:

```
typedef struct vertex{
    char* name;
    Vertex** neighbors;
    float x, y;
}Vertex;

Vertex* create_vertex(char* name, float x, float y){
    Vertex* vertex = (Vertex*) malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    vertex->x = x;
    vertex->y = y;
    vertex->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(name) + 1);
    strcpy(vertex->name, name);
    vertex->neighbors = (Vertex**) malloc(sizeof(Vertex*));
    vertex->neighbors[0] = NULL;

return vertex;
}

void creates_connection(Vertex* v1, Vertex* v2){
    if(areNeighbors(v1, v2)){
        printf("Vertices ja sao vizinhos");
        return;
    }

    Vertex** real;

    if(v1->neighbors[0] == NULL){
        real = (Vertex**) realloc(v1->neighbors, sizeof(Vertex*)+1);

        if(real != NULL){
            v1->neighbors = real;
            v1->neighbors[0] = v2;
            v1->neighbors[1] = NULL;
        }else printf("Nao foi possivel realocar memoria");

    }else{
        Vertex* aux = v1->neighbors[0];
        int i = 0;

        while(aux != NULL){
            aux = v1->neighbors[i];
            i++;
        }

        real= (Vertex**) realloc(v1->neighbors, (sizeof(Vertex*))*(i+1));

        if(real!= NULL){
            v1->neighbors= real;
            v1->neighbors[i] = v2;
            v1->neighbors[i+1] = NULL;
        }else printf("Nao foi possivel realocar memoria");
    }

    if(v2->neighbors[0] == NULL){
        real = (Vertex**) realloc(v2->neighbors, sizeof(Vertex*));

        if(real != NULL){
            v2->neighbors = realocado;
            v2->neighbors[0] = v1;
            v2->neighbors[1] = NULL;
        }

    }else{
        Vertex* aux = v2->neighbors[0];
        int i = 0;

        while(aux != NULL){
            aux = v2->neighbors[i];
            i++;
        }

        //HERE, BELLOW, IT CRASHES, DOESN'T PASS TO THE IF
        real = (Vertex**) realloc(v2->neighbors, (sizeof(Vertex*))*(i+1));

        if(real != NULL){
            v2->neighbors = real;
            v2->neighbors[i] = v1;
            v2->neighbors[i+1] = NULL;
        }else printf("Nao foi possivel realcoar memoria");

    }
}
```

I don't know if it is the best way to do what im triying to do, and i accept suggestions, but i would also like to understand what is going on, i mean, why is this SIGABRT happening.

Comment: `real = (Vertex**) realloc(v1->neighbors, sizeof(Vertex*)+1);`  Should probably be  -->>  `real = (Vertex**) realloc(v1->neighbors, sizeof(Vertex*)*2);`

Comment: How is `Vertex` defined?

Comment: This is for sure wrong `realloc(v1->neighbors, sizeof(Vertex*)+1);` Normally, it would look like `realloc(v1->neighbors, (current_size+1) * sizeof(Vertex*));` I also think the type is wrong

Comment: Vertex is a abstract data type, wich contains two variables float and one variable char*. I think i can see the error, the "+1" only adds a byte to the memory reallocation, right?

Comment: @yamunaq - yep, that is for sure a bug. But I think there is more problems than that. To get help, post the code for `Vertex`

Comment: I'm new here, can i post the code here in comments or should i edit the post?

Comment: @yamunaq Edit the post

Comment: Ok, done. Please tell me if there is more information i can provide.

Comment: What is `Vertice`? Did you mean `Vertex` ? or `struct vertex` ?

Comment: Sorry, i'm brazilian and i fixed a thing in my original code and wrote in portuguese. Already fixed.

Comment: @yamunaq notice that I updated my answer because there was a problem in my first code

Answer (score 0):

This answer focus on pointing to (some of) the problems in the posted code. In the end this answer contains a suggestion for a code change that will work with your current design. If your willing to make a redesign take a look at the answer from @wildplasser

There are a problem here

```
if(v1->neighbors[0] == NULL){
    real = (Vertex**) realloc(v1->neighbors, sizeof(Vertex*)+1);
                                                           ^^^^
                                               This only increase with 1 byte
                                               but you want 1 pointer
```

and here

```
if(v2->neighbors[0] == NULL){
    real = (Vertex**) realloc(v2->neighbors, sizeof(Vertex*));
                                                        ^^^^
                                               No increase at all
```

Further there is a problem here:

```
    Vertex* aux = v1->neighbors[0];
    int i = 0;

    while(aux != NULL){
        aux = v1->neighbors[i];
        i++;
    }

    real= (Vertex**) realloc(v1->neighbors, (sizeof(Vertex*))*(i+1));
```

As your design requires that the array always have a NULL pointer at the end, you need to let `i` start at 1, i.e.

```
    int i = 1;
```

Also this part has a problem as you write out side allocated memory - remember that the index start from zero:

```
    real= (Vertex**) realloc(v1->neighbors, (sizeof(Vertex*))*(i+1));

    if(real!= NULL){
        v1->neighbors= real;
        v1->neighbors[i] = v2;
        v1->neighbors[i+1] = NULL;  // UPS... write outside allocated memory
                                    // Writing to [i+1] requires that you
                                    // have i+2 pointers but you only
                                    // have i+1
```

The interesting part is that you don't need the two special cases for handling when the first pointer is `NULL`. The code in the `else` can also handle the case where the first pointer is NULL.

So this code:

```
if(v1->neighbors[0] == NULL){
    real = (Vertex**) realloc(v1->neighbors, sizeof(Vertex*)+1);

    if(real != NULL){
        v1->neighbors = real;
        v1->neighbors[0] = v2;
        v1->neighbors[1] = NULL;
    }else printf("Nao foi possivel realocar memoria");

}else{
    Vertex* aux = v1->neighbors[0];
    int i = 0;

    while(aux != NULL){
        aux = v1->neighbors[i];
        i++;
    }

    real= (Vertex**) realloc(v1->neighbors, (sizeof(Vertex*))*(i+1));

    if(real!= NULL){
        v1->neighbors= real;
        v1->neighbors[i] = v2;
        v1->neighbors[i+1] = NULL;
    }else printf("Nao foi possivel realocar memoria");
}
```

can be simplified to

```
    Vertex* aux = v1->neighbors[0];
    int i = 1;         // NOTICE: Use 1 instead of 0

    while(aux != NULL){
        aux = v1->neighbors[i];
        i++;
    }

    real= (Vertex**) realloc(v1->neighbors, (sizeof(Vertex*))*(i+1));

    if(real!= NULL){
        v1->neighbors= real;
        v1->neighbors[i-1] = v2;   // NOTICE: i-1
        v1->neighbors[i] = NULL;   // NOTICE: i
    }else printf("Nao foi possivel realocar memoria");
```

This also goes for the second block where you handle `v2`

Answer (score 0):

- instead of a NULL sentinel at the end of your pointer-array, you could keep track of the (used)size
- dont reallocate on every addition, use larger increments
- if the first argument is NULL, realloc()works just like malloc()
- centralize your(re)allocs, that will concentrate your bugs
- a static function will be inlined (at some optimisation level)

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct vertex{
    char* name;
    float x, y;
    unsigned size, used;
    struct vertex **neighbors;
    };

struct vertex *create_vertex(char* name, float x, float y){
    struct vertex *vv = malloc(sizeof *vv );

    vv->x = x;
    vv->y = y;
    vv->name = strdup(name);
    vv->size=0;
    vv->used=0;
    vv->neighbors = NULL;

return vv;
}

static void resize_vertex(struct vertex *pp, unsigned newsize)
{
struct vertex **tmp;

if (!newsize)newsize =4;
tmp = realloc(pp->neighbors, newsize * sizeof *pp->neighbors );
if(!tmp) { /* handlefailure */ }

pp->neighbors = tmp;
pp->size = newsize;
}


void creates_connection(struct vertex* v1, struct vertex* v2){
    if(areNeighbors(v1, v2)){
        printf("Vertices ja sao vizinhos");
        return;
    }

    if(v1->used== v1->size) resize_vertex(v1, 2*v1->size);
    v1->neighbors[v1->used] = v2;
    v1->used += 1;

return;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for indent, since there arent any nested blocks;-)